# Why is this database error occuring?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the JQuery .post method to get data using an AJAX call.  The PHP file that is rendering the data has the following code that inputs information into a database:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO  questions(question, added_by) VALUES ('$question', '$user_id')";   

 $result = mysql_result($query); 

        //If db error
        if(!$result )
        {
            $error = str_replace("'", "*", mysql_error());
            $method = __METHOD__.'line: '.__LINE__; 
            return Error::db_error($method, $error, $this->ip, 'An internal error has occurred.  Your question can not be added at this time.');
         }
```

According to this code, a database error is occurring, yet mysql_error() is blank.  When I use die($query), and copy and paste the literal query string into my mysql gui window (sqlyog) and run the query, it inserts just fine with no warnings or errors.

I have this general set-up for some other PHP functions and it works just fine.

I am really stumped by this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `Manning - Bobby Tables in Action`, special bonus edition!

Comment: Have you tried running the query with `mysql_query` before using `mysql_result` ? That _might_ fix it.

Comment: Do you have an active connection at the time? can you verify it via `mysql_stat()`?

Comment: Does your SQL statement work if you directly execute it against the DB?

Comment: run tests step by step until you find the problem.

Comment: Why did my question get a -2 vote?  It was reasonable, and I explained the steps I had taken before asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the query using `mysql_query` before Retrieving the contents of cells from a `MySQL result set` using `mysql_result`.

```
   $result = mysql_query($query); 
   echo mysql_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an encoding issue? What is your contentType on the Ajax post?